# How can I read density fluctuation from microwaves?

Tags: cosmology, temperature, big-bang

The Cosmic Microwave Background Radiation shows temperature differences. The red and yellow areas are warmer. The green and blue areas are cooler.

For example consider this picture of CMBR fluctuations:

[image: CMBR fluctuations]

I've read it also shows density fluctuations, but how I can identify them? Where does it have more matter and will form stars and galaxies? And where will it be empty space?

Comment: this picture shows us fluctuations of temperature on the scale of $10^{-5}$ to $10^{-6}$ Kelvin, if it is from the WMAP survey. It is really hard to give the mapping of primordial density fluctuations and the position of galaxies how we observe them today. My first guess would be the more energy the more matter has formed around there. Maybe you can update the image with another one which has some coordinates and legend attached?